# New action in index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have my new view and action (which displays a form in a modal dialogue) to be contained within the index view. How can I do this? Right now I get an error, and I assume it's because I have `<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>` when `@video` is only defined in the new view and not the index view. I'm not sure how to correct this though...

Comment: well now there's a new problem that's somewhat related if you'd like to take a crack at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415358/weird-error-with-user-edit-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@video = Video.new` in your video controller:

```
def index
   @video = Video.new
end
```