# Weird error with User edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, undefined

When I click on this link in my `index` view:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Password", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#edit

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/_modal.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <div id="boxes">
2: <div id="dialog" class="window">
3: <%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
```

This has to do with a partial called `_modal` that I render into the `index`view. It has a form in it.

I also have this in my Videos controller:

```
def index
  @video = Video.new
  @videos = Video.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

UPDATE:

Here's my edit action in the Users controller:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end
```

Here's the `_modal` partial:

```
<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :video_url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :video_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title, 'Song Title' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Cancel', '#', :class => 'close' %>
   </div>
   <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your `edit` action and your `_modal.html.erb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are basically having the same problem as last time.

Since you are effectively rendering the `edit` action—whether it is in a modal or not—you need `@video` defined again.

Comment: Well, it really depends on what you are trying to do. If you are having AJAX to display the modal (correct me if I'm wrong), every time one of those templates gets displayed, the server has to render it, and every time it gets rendered, it needs access to those instance variables. In this case, it needs it to build the form. Maybe if you post more about what your goal is, we can try to see if there's a better way to approach it. Also, in times like this, `before_filter`s can be your friend ;)

Comment: Not AJAX, the modal is always there but hidden, and clicking a click makes it appear. This is probably not the best way to do it though :/

Comment: Hmmm... how could I use `before_filter` in this case?

Comment: Well, if for whatever reason every action in this controller needs to have access to a `Video.new`, you could define a protected method in the controller such as `def new_video; @video = Video.new; end;` and then do `before_filter :new_video`.

Comment: yeah, although I also need it in different controllers. In that case, I guess I could make the before_filter global in my application controller?

Comment: You could do that, but do you need it in all controllers? I would maybe advise making a protected method of `ApplicationController` (or a module that gets included) and then making it a `before_filter` only in the controllers that you need it in.